# sorting in codeigniter without pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, sorting

Can anyone help me to sort a single column of a table, (only in ascending order) with code-igniter. (excluding pagination). Am not interested in doing this with java-script. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to sort a single column

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('yourtablename');
$this->db->order_by("column_name", "ASC"); // or lower case asc
// $this->db->limit(1); limits the number of results.
$query = $this->db->get(); 
return $query->result();
```

Comment: hi, sorry for late reply. i tried the method u posted here. but the result is like 1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,2,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,3 etc. but i need it in 1,2,3,4,5 order. pls help

Comment: i got it. it was because my field was defined as varchar instead of int. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*')
         ->from('table_name')
         ->order_by('col_name','ASC');
$query = $this->db->get();
if($query->num_rows()>0){
    return $query->result_array();
}else{
    return false;
}
```